# passing argument 2 of ‘strcat’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]

Tags: c, fifo, strcat

I am reading off a fifo, and then I try to make a another array in different format out of it.
I know buf gets its values as expected, since printing it out is good.

```
char graphic[100];
char buf[100];
read(fd_read,&buf,50);
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
strcat(graphic, buf[i]); }
```

gives me error:

> passing argument 2 of ‘strcat’ makes pointer from integer without a
>   cast [-Wint-conversion]

I use eclipse on linux, on C.
...HELP?

Comment: What is `whichCharIsIt`? Please tell in real code `graphic` is well initialized.

Comment: I put it back to its simple format. graphic is all good, i checked

Comment: `strcat(graphic, buf[i]);` --> `graphic[i] =  buf[i];` ?

Comment: Check the data types atleast once before posting these questions. You'll save yourself the hassle of logging into SO altogether...

Answer (score 4):

Signature of `strcat` is:

```
char *strcat(char *dest, const char *src);
```

i.e. second argument should be pointer to `char` array that terminates with `'\0'`. In your case you are passing a single `char`acter.

Instead of `for(int i=0; i<10; i++){ strcat(graphic, buf[i]); }`, you possibly need just: (Assuming `graphic` is initialized somewhere)

```
strcat(graphic, buf); /* Use strncat for limited number of characters */
```

Also make sure that `string.h` is included in your program.

---

To append the characters by yourself, you can use just assignation than using a function.

```
/* Append one character (ith character of buf[i] ) */
const size_t len = strlen(graphic);
if(len + 1 >= sizeof graphics) { /* Error handling */ }
else {
  graphic[len] = buf[i];
  graphic[len + 1] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: so i should add a new char, which includes buf[i] +  '\0' before inserting it to graphic array by strcat ???

Comment: but i need to insert some more chars between the chars of buf, meaning i have o change it sometimes. I do need to get it char by char

Comment: In that case, append the characters yourself.

Comment: still, not working

Comment: **Not working**: Now I will check my crystal ball to read your mind and understand what exactly didn't work.

Comment: This `if(len + 1 > sizeof graphics)` should be `if(len + 1 >= sizeof graphic)`, shouldn't it?

Comment: @alk Thanks, you are right. I will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

syntaxt of strcat():

```
char *strcat(char *dest, const char *src);
```

The two parameters should be character pointers. In your code, buf is a character pointer(or an array) but in the second parameter to the call to strcat, you didn't send the entire array(buf) thus making it as a character.

try this instead, this might meet your requirements:

```
char graphic[100];
char buf[100];
read(fd_read, &buf, 50);

strcpy(graphic, "");
strncat(graphic, buf, 10); //last parameter tells you how many bytes to append
```

Once refer the below link for more information regarding the error:

[C strcat - warning: passing arg 2 of `strcat' makes pointer from integer without a cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19307600/c-strcat-warning-passing-arg-2-of-strcat-makes-pointer-from-integer-without)

Comment: `strcat()`ing to an uninitialised buffer (`graphic` here) invokes the infamous Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: @alk, yes. Garbage values will be present in the graphics array to which the buffer array is appended. I have edited my answer in order to remove such kind of behaviour. :-)